# red black tree insertion

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, red-black-tree-insertion

I inserted node 36 in the red black tree and the following red black tree resulted:

[image]

my problem is that how to handle double red in this special case? is it case 2 or 3?

Comment: I suppose you mean case 2 or 3 of your list of rebalancing operations, but you should be aware that everybody doesn't have the same numbering (let alone rules). The only general rule of thumb I can give you is: first rule that fits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree)'s properties and cases...

**`36` would be inserted under case 5, rotating `22` left.**

> The parent P is red but the uncle is black or not there.

Wikipedia just says "the uncle is black", but, looking at the code, you'll see that that case triggers.

---

Note that the tree without `36` was already invalid because property 5 (all paths from any given node to its leaf nodes contain the same number of black nodes) is not held:

- 20 to 15 contains 1 black node
- 20 to 30 contains 2 black nodes

Assuming the insert order is `20, 15, 22, 30, 36`...

All nodes are inserted as red.

`22` would be inserted under case 2.

> The parent is black.

`30` would be inserted under case 3, making `22` and `15` black and `20` red.

> The parent and uncle are red; both are repainted black and the grandparent becomes red.

`36` would be inserted under case 5, rotating `22` left.

> The parent P is red but the uncle is black or not there.

Answer (score 0):

22 not have a left child

therefore..

case 1: Restructuring

we will left rotation

30 --> root "black"

22--> left child "red"

36--> right child "red"